# RSelenium scraping for Disqus comments

Tags: html, css, web-scraping, webdriver, rselenium

I'm trying to scrape or obtain the text of Disqus comments from an online local newspaper using RSelenium in Chrome but am finding the going a little tough for my capabilities. I have searched many places but did not find the right information or I am using the wrong search terms (most probably).

So far I have managed to get the "normal" html from the pages but cannot pinpoint the right class, css selector or id to get the Disqus comments. I have also tried Selectorgadget but this only points to `#dsq-app2` which selects the whole Disqus area at once and does not allow to select smaller parts of the area. I tried the same with RSelenium using `elems <- mybrowser$findElement(using = "id", "dsq-app2")` with an "environment" being stored in `elems`. Then I tried to find child elements within `elems` but came up blank.

Viewing the page via developer tools I can see that the interesting stuff is within an iframe called `#dsq-app2` and have managed to extract all its source through the `elems$getPageSource()` after switching to the frame using `elems$switchToFrame("dsq-app2")`. This outputs all the html as one big "dirty" chunk and short of searching for the required stuff held in `<p>` tags and other elements of interest such as poster's usernames in `data-role="username"` and others, I don't seem to find the right way forward.

I have also tried using the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267489/scrape-comments-generated-with-javascript-using-rselenium-xml) but the Disqus setup is a little different. One of the pages I'm trying is [this](http://www.maltatoday.com.mt/news/national/67431/education_minister_says_that_mixing_with_different_social_groups_is_essential_to_education#disqus_thread) with the bulk of the comments area within a section called `conversation` and a ton of other id's such as `posts` and the un-ordered list with the `id=post-list` that ultimately carries the comments I need to scrape.

Any ideas or help tips are most welcome and received with thanks.

Comment: can you post the URL of the newspaper?

Comment: In my last paragraph I have a link in the second line :-). http://www.maltatoday.com.mt/news/national/67431/education_minister_says_that_mixing_with_different_social_groups_is_essential_to_education#.V4S1m7iF6Uk

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of testing and experimenting I managed. I don't know if it's the cleanest or prettiest solution but it works. Hope others will find it useful. Basically what I did was to find the url that points to the comments only. This is found within the "dsq-app2" `iframe` and is an `attribute` called `src`. At first I was also switching to the iframe but found that this works without.

```
remDr$navigate("toTheRequiredPage")
elemsource <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "dsq-app2")
src <- elemsource$getElementAttribute("src") # find the src attribute within the iframe`
remDr$navigate(src[[1]]) # navigate to the src url

# find the posts from the new page
elem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "posts")
elem.posts <- elem$findChildElements(using = "id", value = "post-list")
elem.msgs <- elem.posts[[1]]$findChildElements(using = "class name", value = "post-message")

length(elem.msgs)
msgtext <- elem.msgs[[1]]$getElementText() # find first post's text
msgtext # print message
```

Update: I found out that if I use `remDr$switchToFrame("dsq-app2")` I do not need to use the `src` url as I have explained above. So there are actually two ways of scraping;

1. Use `switchToFrame("nameOfFrame")` or
2. Use my prior solution of using the `src` URL from the iframe

Hope this makes it clearer.